# Can't resolve 'ws' in "puppeteer-core/lib"

Tags: webpack, electron, puppeteer

I am well aware that questions with similar title have already been asked here, but all of them are happening in certain scenarios whereas my scenario is different,(I think).

I am building an electron app (using [Nextron](https://github.com/saltyshiomix/nextron) to create a boilerplate basically)

My requirement is to use puppeteer library inside my electron app to get information from some webpages.
Everything is working as expected, but when I try to include 'puppeteer-core' module into my app, the following error starts to come up.

[WS error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RJty.png)

After following other threads here, as well as Github issues, the most popular response is the following :

```
const config = {
// ...
externals: {
    puppeteer: 'require("puppeteer")',
    // ...
},
```

};

Since I am using next.js the best place I could find to add this snippet was in next.config.js

```
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');
module.exports = withCSS({
    webpack: (config) => {
        config.target = 'electron-renderer';
        config.module.rules = [
            ...(config.module.rules || []),
            {
                test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
                use: 'url-loader?limit=100000',
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader!raw-loader!postcss-loader!sass-loader'
            }
        ];
        config.externals = {
            puppeteer :'require("puppeteer")'
        }
        return config;
    },
});
```

But as soon as I do that, another strange error starts coming up

[Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgzaL.png)

Can someone please help me, I am not able to figure out what is exactly happening here.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution? I'm trying to do a similar thing, but in Vue using electron-vue getting the same error.

Comment: @mvaneijgen No one helped in this regard, but I was able to solve it using electron-webpack. Its very straightforward to use and you can use any framework with it